# In DEFI does each token-pair produce its own LP token?

Tags: uniswap, liquidity-provider

In DEFI does each token-pair produce its own LP token?

Let us say I am in uniswap does each token pair produce its own LP pair when you provide liquidity or is it just one LP token regardless of the liquidity pool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Uniswap is an automated liquidity protocol powered by a constant product formula and implemented in a system of non-upgradeable smart contracts on the Ethereum blockchain. [...]
> Each Uniswap smart contract, or pair, manages a liquidity pool made up of reserves of two ERC-20 tokens.
> Anyone can become a liquidity provider (LP) for a pool by depositing an equivalent value of each underlying token in return for pool tokens. These tokens track pro-rata LP shares of the total reserves, and can be redeemed for the underlying assets at any time.

https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/protocol-overview/how-uniswap-works/

In brief: your LP tokens are "shares" of a particular LP. Therefore each LP (or token pair) produces its own LP token.

Comment: "your LP tokens are "shares" of a particular LP". That was the simple to understand explanation I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: If your LP tokens are "shares" of a particular LP can you see the total number of shares in an LP?

Comment: You can see how many LP tokens exist. For example for the UMA/ETH LP pool you'll find the total supply at https://etherscan.io/token/0x88d97d199b9ed37c29d846d00d443de980832a22 

Knowing how many tokens you hold it's easy to get your share of the pool.

Comment: is a LP token for `(token1, token2)` the same as for `(token2, token1)`? Are these pairs deemed identical in a LP?